# UIBarButtonItem for 4 tabs in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a UITabBarController which contains 4 tabs. On each tab there should be an icon within the navigationbar which allows the user to open my settings view. I solved this by creating a parent class for those 4 tabs and added an icon within the viewDidLoad method which calls a method that does the push. This soluation worked as expected so far.

But :-)! Now I would like to have this settings view open only one time. The solution I have at the moment allows the user to open the settings view on all 4 tabs simultaniously. I don't want that - Is there an approach to have the settings open only one time?

Here's my code (which is placed in the parent file)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(showSettings)];
}

- (void)showSettings
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] animated:YES];
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your tabs are `UINavigationController`s, in `-showSettings` walk the other tabs and pop the navigation view controller if it's a `SettingsViewController`.

```
- (void)showSettings
{
    for (UINavigationController *navController in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
        if ([navController.viewControllers.lastObject isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]])
             [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 4 UINavigationControllers for each tab, and each of the rootViews they push has this icon in the Navigation bar, right? If so, once the user has navigated to he settings view, then you need to send a message to each UINavigationController, telling it to remove the Settings UIBarButtonItem from its UINavigationBar.

Now the UINavigationController does not "own" all the UINavigationItems used by the view controllers, so it will have to message all the view controllers it current has and tell them they should remove the button.

You can do this as you present your settings view, so that when the user returns to the main view, the button is gone, and its gone from all other view controllers too.